# Accessing $stateParams in custom ui-router config property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to access `$stateParams` in a custom ui-router state config property, but all I get when logging it is a blank object.

Which is to be expected, since I am deviating from the default ui-router config, and I completely understand that, but I am playing around with ui-router and am trying to replicate the `resolve` functionality using a custom configuration object, so I need to have access to the `$stateParams` in said config object.

My goal is just to be able to resolve a set of promises, that might require access to the `$stateParams`.

Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kpzNGOyae7hqpGBFL825?p=preview).

Comment: really not clear what the issue is or what you are trying to achieve. What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: you had a typo in your ``$stateProvider`` code. Change the ``custom`` to ``resolve``, and you should get it working

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the "resolve" in your states:

Here the code

```
        .state('app.test', {
        url: '/test/:id',
        controller: 'testController',
        resolve: {
            resolveableDate: ['$stateParams', 'AwesomeService', function($stateParams, AwesomeService) {

                // this is blank, as is to be expected
                console.log($stateParams);

                return AwesomeService.getData($stateParams.id);
            }]
        }
    });
```

Link of demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/rmuh3gt8K7CXMxwkRjaD?p=preview

You can resolve promises with the resolve without problem.

Comment: Hi Scoup, thanks for the answer. I am aware of that, yes, but as I mentioned, I am explicitly passing in the `custom` config object, and are trying to manually `resolve` it by invoking it via `$injector`, as you'll see in the `$stateChangeStart` event block. My problem is that I can't access the `$stateParams` in the `custom` object, which is where the problem comes in, how do I somehow get access to the `$stateParams` in the `custom` object? I am aware of the fact that this is a very strange way of doing it, and that it should not be done that way,  but there is method to my madness.

Comment: Hun... now I understood your problem, but did not understand why you can't use the resolve. But if you see here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/state.js#L1105 the states params are set just before resolve the promises, and if you check here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y1IfCD85lyESN8pzRfW1?p=preview the custom fields are called before the resolves, so I think you can't do that.